# Packer Timeout waiting for SSH error with VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, packer

Although I could ssh manually in VirtualBox, Packer does not know if ssh connection is established.
I've seen the same issues, but I could not find any solution for this.
My purpose of using packer is to convert my existing ovf file to Digital Ocean droplet, so that I could use it in my Digital Ocean server.

**template.json**

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
      "source_path": "/Users/seoyoochan/Desktop/work/G4M_3.1.2_OVF_demo/G4M_centos6_demo.ovf",
      "ssh_username": "root",
      "ssh_password": "g4mg4m$$",
      "boot_command":[
        "root<return>",
        "g4mg4m$$<return>"
      ],
      "headless": true,
      "boot_wait": "30s",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": ["vagrant"]
}
```

---

**Running packer build without debug option**

```
➜  G4M_3.1.2_OVF_demo  packer build template.json
virtualbox-ovf output will be in this color.

==> virtualbox-ovf: Downloading or copying Guest additions
    virtualbox-ovf: Downloading or copying: file:///Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> virtualbox-ovf: Importing VM: /Users/seoyoochan/Desktop/work/G4M_3.1.2_OVF_demo/G4M_centos6_demo.ovf
==> virtualbox-ovf: Creating forwarded port mapping for SSH (host port 3249)
==> virtualbox-ovf: Starting the virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-ovf: Waiting 10s for boot...
==> virtualbox-ovf: Typing the boot command...
==> virtualbox-ovf: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> virtualbox-ovf: Timeout waiting for SSH.
==> virtualbox-ovf: Unregistering and deleting imported VM...
==> virtualbox-ovf: Error deleting VM: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: Cannot unregister the machine 'packer-virtualbox-ovf-1451547904' while it is locked
==> virtualbox-ovf: VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
==> virtualbox-ovf: VBoxManage: error: Context: "Unregister(CleanupMode_DetachAllReturnHardDisksOnly, ComSafeArrayAsOutParam(aMedia))" at line 155 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
==> virtualbox-ovf: Deleting output directory...
Build 'virtualbox-ovf' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-ovf: Timeout waiting for SSH.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

**When I ran in debug mode**

```
==> virtualbox-ovf: Waiting for SSH to become available...
2015/12/31 17:43:48 packer-builder-virtualbox-ovf: 2015/12/31 17:43:48 [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3581: getsockopt: connection refused
2015/12/31 17:43:53 packer-builder-virtualbox-ovf: 2015/12/31 17:43:53 [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3581: getsockopt: connection refused
2015/12/31 17:43:58 packer-builder-virtualbox-ovf: 2015/12/31 17:43:58 [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3581: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Comment: how do you run in debug mode? like this: `packer build -debug config.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this error was because eth0 device does not present, which is because new MAC addresses are not overwritten.

There are 2 solutions:
1) remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to get new MAC addresses 
or
2) change `eth0` name to `eth1` like `eth1`, `eth2`, `eth3`

After following either of the above methods, reboot the guest system by typing `reboot`.

check `ifconfig -a`
you will see `eth0` or other ethernet name that you chose.